# inline loop over list to create dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from a variable number of lists. `values` is a two-dimensional list, so `values[0]` is a list. `params_1h` is a list of strings. `rng` is a range of DatetimeIndex. I want to iterate over the number of lists. What is the best way to create a loop over `len(values)`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([values[0],values[1]]), columns = [params_1h[0], params_1h[1]], index = rng)
```

Comment: How about some examples? What should the result look like? What are you having trouble with and why? It looks like you could just do a couple of simple transformations... no loop needed. But it is not clear.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. Now my number of lists in values is two (0 and 1). I want to extend this to for example 7 elements, depending on the number of lists in values (eg 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(values), columns=params_1h, index=rng)
```

From what I understand, you don't need loops. If you want to use the entirety of `values`, just... use `values`. `values` already means `[values[0], values[1], values[2], ... ]`. Same goes for `params_1h`.

Comment: This produces "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly" in "numpy/lib/shape_base.py". I checked that len(values) and len(params_1h) is the same.

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your data. Note that `len()` doesn't give you the shape of the array.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it was my data. One vector is not the same length! Thanks for your help!